# Enclose hyphenation in its own element with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, tei

Given the following XML:

```
<p>
  <lb/>Aber, Schertz bey Seite geſetzet; wer mir und ſo viel ehrlichen
  <lb/>Bieder-Maͤnnern nicht glauben will, der probire es bey den haͤuffigen Kirchen-
  <lb/>Sachen, die ein Sangloser Organiſt etwa geſchmadert hat, (denn es gibt frucht-
  <lb/>bare Naͤchte bey dieſen Leuten,  [...]
</p>
```

Is there a pure XSLT way of transforming this into this?

```
<p>
  <lb/>Aber, Schertz bey Seite geſetzet; wer mir und ſo viel ehrlichen
  <lb/>Bieder-Maͤnnern nicht glauben will, der probire es bey den haͤuffigen Kirchen<pc force="strong">-</pc>
  <lb/>Sachen, die ein Sangloser Organiſt etwa geſchmadert hat, (denn es gibt frucht<pc force="weak">-</pc>
  <lb/>bare Naͤchte bey dieſen Leuten,  [...]
</p>
```

If the first letter following the `<lb>` element is a capital letter, the `force` attribute should be `strong`, otherwise it is `weak`.

At the moment I am completly stuck on how to select a text node that ends with certain letter (`-`) with a `<lb>`-sibling that is itself followed by capital letter ...

Comment: The text nodes don't seem to end with `-`, rather with `-` followed by white space like a line break and spaces. Nevertheless, you should be able to test for that using `matches(., '-\s*$')`, assuming XSLT 2 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XSLT 3 (but only for declaring the identity transformation with `xsl:mode` and using `||` instead of `concat()` and `analyze-string` which could be replaced by `xsl:analyze-string`) [the following sample](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet+xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A++version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A++xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A++exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A++expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A++%0D%0A++%3Cxsl%3Aparam+name%3D%22sep%22+as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%3E-%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0D%0A++%0D%0A++%3Cxsl%3Aparam+name%3D%22pattern%22+as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22+select%3D%22%27%28%27+%7C%7C+%24sep+%7C%7C+%27%29%27+%7C%7C+%27%28%5Cs*%29%24%27%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A++%3Cxsl%3Amode+on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++%0D%0A++%3Cxsl%3Atemplate+match%3D%22p%2Ftext%28%29%5Bmatches%28.%2C+%24pattern%29%5D%5Bfollowing-sibling%3A%3Anode%28%29%5B1%5D%5Bself%3A%3Alb%5D%5D%22%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22replace%28.%2C+%24pattern%2C+%27%27%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cpc+force%3D%22%7Bif+%28following-sibling%3A%3Anode%28%29%5B2%5D%5Bself%3A%3Atext%28%29%5Bmatches%28.%2C+%27%5E%5Cp%7BLu%7D%27%29%5D%5D%29+then+%27strong%27+else+%27weak%27%7D%22%3E%7B%24sep%7D%3C%2Fpc%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22analyze-string%28.%2C+%24pattern%29%2F%2F*%3Agroup%5B%40nr+%3D+2%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Cp%3E%0D%0A++%3Clb%2F%3EAber%2C+Schertz+bey+Seite+ge%C5%BFetzet%3B+wer+mir+und+%C5%BFo+viel+ehrlichen%0D%0A++%3Clb%2F%3EBieder-Ma%CD%A4nnern+nicht+glauben+will%2C+der+probire+es+bey+den+ha%CD%A4uffigen+Kirchen-%0D%0A++%3Clb%2F%3ESachen%2C+die+ein+Sangloser+Organi%C5%BFt+etwa+ge%C5%BFchmadert+hat%2C+%28denn+es+gibt+frucht-%0D%0A++%3Clb%2F%3Ebare+Na%CD%A4chte+bey+die%C5%BFen+Leuten%2C++%5B...%5D%0D%0A%3C%2Fp%3E&input-type=XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string">-</xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string" select="'(' || $sep || ')' || '(\s*)$'"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="p/text()[matches(., $pattern)][following-sibling::node()[1][self::lb]]">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $pattern, '')"/>
    <pc force="{if (following-sibling::node()[2][self::text()[matches(., '^\p{Lu}')]]) then 'strong' else 'weak'}">{$sep}</pc>
    <xsl:value-of select="analyze-string(., $pattern)//*:group[@nr = 2]"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

should do. The pattern to match the text node might need to be more specific if a text can be followed by `<lb/><foo>...</foo>`, e.g. the `lb` is not necessarily followed by a text node, as in your sample.